# How to get Json from Request?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I send some parameters to an ASP.NET method using the code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/default.aspx/test.test",
        type: "POST",
        data: "{'parameter':'kapdbe'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Then how can I get the data sent from HttpContext.Request ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not in `result` within the `success()` callback?

Comment: @Orbling: He wants to get the request data on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the raw data from `Request.InputStream` into a string using a `StreamReader`, then parse the JSON from the string.

If you're using a page method, you can simply modify the page method to take a `[Serializable]` class as a parameter, with properties that match the incoming JSON.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks. My problem is now that I would like to use context.Session. I marked the class with IRequiresSessionState interface, but after I set Session["xyz"] to a value, second time is is null. What causes this ?

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

```
url: "/default.aspx/test.test"
```

So, I'm guessing **ASP.NET WebForms** right?

> It's always good to put this info in the question tags, so we can help you better and quicker

So, you should do this:

```
url: "/json/test.ashx"
```

And create that **Generic Handler** (So you don't need to have all the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle to handle, and it will be much faster)

the code will be as:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        // Get your variable
        string param = context.Request["parameter"];

        // Do something with it    
        MyObject output = DoSomethingWithPAram(param);

        // Use Json.NET to get a nice JSON string
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);

        // Output new stuff
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(json);
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps ... if it's **ASP.NET MVC 2 / 3** It's a little easier :)

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Wish I could give another +1 for the comment about MVC (it really is easier).